# How to calculate bitrate of lower resolution videos created from high resolution video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to implement HLS video using ffmpeg. Suppose I have a video with following specs:

```
1080x1920 bitrate: 20971649
```

Now I have to write a command to convert it to for example: 720p. So now the actual converted video by ffmpeg has bitrate: `760808`.

Is there a way that I can know this bitrate before hand, so that I can include in the master playlist correctly?

Comment: Only if you are setting a bitrate target during encode along with other parameters to remain close to target. With recent versions of ffmpeg, when you encode, ffmpeg will write the bitrate to the master playlist automatically.

Comment: @Gyan `ffmpeg` doesn't create a master playlist, right? It creates playlist for a particular resolution and then we have to create a master playlist. Or is there some command that also creates the master playlist?

Comment: ffmpeg has been to render multiple renditions and create master+variant playlists in single command since 4.0.

Comment: @Gyan can you give me a link to command

Comment: @Gyan can you help me once more? I want all my videos to be exported as 720p/mp4 as fast as possible. So if the video resolution is lower, I just want it to be encoded it to mp4, if it isn't already. If resolution is more than 720p then I want it to rescale it to 720p. No HLS stuff here. I know how to do them in individual commands, but is there any way that I can pass all my videos through one command and get the desired output?